# Unable to copy multiple files non-interactively with single command

Tags: copy, solaris, interactive, file-copying, non-interactive

I wish to force copy a set of files having either the same or different names to a single destination on the same host **with a single command** onn Solaris.

Note: the copy should be forced and non-interactive.

I emptied the destination folder using `rm -rf *` and then fired the copy command as below which does not work.

```
ls -ltrq /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war

-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 200209070 Nov 16 15:32 /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war



Gets me an error:

[root@ip-10-237-130-101 ARE_NOCO_15Jan2024_111]# cp -fT /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/Templates/mytemplate1.xls /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/ROOT.war '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war' /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/AUTO_BACKUP/ARE_NOCO_15Jan2024_111/

cp: extra operand '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war'

Try 'cp --help' for more information.

 

Gets me an interactive prompt:

[root@ip-10-137-150-101vNOCO_15Jan2024_111]# cp /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/Templates/mytemplate1.xls /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps/ROOT.war '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/webapps_16Nov2023/ROOT.war' /opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/AUTO_BACKUP/NOCO_15Jan2024_111/

cp: overwrite '/opt/apps/apache-tomcat-10.0.27/AUTO_BACKUP/ARE_NOCO_15Jan2024_111/ROOT.war'?
```

cp command HELP:

```
[root@ip-10-237-120-101 ARE_NOCO_15Jan2024_111]# cp --help

Usage: cp [OPTION]... [-T] SOURCE DEST

  or:  cp [OPTION]... SOURCE... DIRECTORY

  or:  cp [OPTION]... -t DIRECTORY SOURCE...

Copy SOURCE to DEST, or multiple SOURCE(s) to DIRECTORY.

 

Mandatory arguments to long options are mandatory for short options too.

  -a, --archive                same as -dR --preserve=all

      --attributes-only        don't copy the file data, just the attributes

      --backup[=CONTROL]       make a backup of each existing destination file

  -b                           like --backup but does not accept an argument

      --copy-contents          copy contents of special files when recursive

  -d                           same as --no-dereference --preserve=links

  -f, --force                  if an existing destination file cannot be

                                 opened, remove it and try again (this option

                                 is ignored when the -n option is also used)

  -i, --interactive            prompt before overwrite (overrides a previous -n

                                  option)

  -H                           follow command-line symbolic links in SOURCE

  -l, --link                   hard link files instead of copying

  -L, --dereference            always follow symbolic links in SOURCE

  -n, --no-clobber             do not overwrite an existing file (overrides

                                 a previous -i option)

  -P, --no-dereference         never follow symbolic links in SOURCE

  -p                           same as --preserve=mode,ownership,timestamps

      --preserve[=ATTR_LIST]   preserve the specified attributes (default:

                                 mode,ownership,timestamps), if possible

                                 additional attributes: context, links, xattr,

                                 all

  -c                           deprecated, same as --preserve=context

      --no-preserve=ATTR_LIST  don't preserve the specified attributes

      --parents                use full source file name under DIRECTORY

  -R, -r, --recursive          copy directories recursively

      --reflink[=WHEN]         control clone/CoW copies. See below

      --remove-destination     remove each existing destination file before

                                 attempting to open it (contrast with --force)

      --sparse=WHEN            control creation of sparse files. See below

      --strip-trailing-slashes  remove any trailing slashes from each SOURCE

                                 argument

  -s, --symbolic-link          make symbolic links instead of copying

  -S, --suffix=SUFFIX          override the usual backup suffix

  -t, --target-directory=DIRECTORY  copy all SOURCE arguments into DIRECTORY

  -T, --no-target-directory    treat DEST as a normal file

  -u, --update                 copy only when the SOURCE file is newer

                                 than the destination file or when the

                                 destination file is missing

  -v, --verbose                explain what is being done

  -x, --one-file-system        stay on this file system

  -Z                           set SELinux security context of destination

                                 file to default type

      --context[=CTX]          like -Z, or if CTX is specified then set the

                                 SELinux or SMACK security context to CTX

      --help     display this help and exit

      --version  output version information and exit

 

By default, sparse SOURCE files are detected by a crude heuristic and the

corresponding DEST file is made sparse as well.  That is the behavior

selected by --sparse=auto.  Specify --sparse=always to create a sparse DEST

file whenever the SOURCE file contains a long enough sequence of zero bytes.

Use --sparse=never to inhibit creation of sparse files.

 

When --reflink[=always] is specified, perform a lightweight copy, where the

data blocks are copied only when modified.  If this is not possible the copy

fails, or if --reflink=auto is specified, fall back to a standard copy.

Use --reflink=never to ensure a standard copy is performed.

 

The backup suffix is '~', unless set with --suffix or SIMPLE_BACKUP_SUFFIX.

The version control method may be selected via the --backup option or through

the VERSION_CONTROL environment variable.  Here are the values:

 

  none, off       never make backups (even if --backup is given)

  numbered, t     make numbered backups

  existing, nil   numbered if numbered backups exist, simple otherwise

  simple, never   always make simple backups

 

As a special case, cp makes a backup of SOURCE when the force and backup

options are given and SOURCE and DEST are the same name for an existing,

regular file.
```

Kindly suggest.